# Блокировка сертификата COMODO

Tags: ssl

Недавно поступили жалобы на то, что пользователи не могут зайти на сайт из-за проблем с сертификатом (ошибку выдает браузер). После этого погуглил и наткнулся на статью, которая была опубликована год назад, и там говорится что

> Роскомнадзор на основании решения суда 2013 года заблокировал ресурсы крупнейшего поставщика сертификатов SSL(речь идет про COMODO)

Так вот, у меня как раз и стоит бесплатный сертификат COMODO от CloudFlare, что посоветуете мне теперь делать?

Comment: Подайте в суд на незаконную блокировку и так по инстанциям до верховного суда, потом можно в европейский суд, если не будет вынесено решение в вашу пользу. А там можно и компенсацию требовать в несколько миллионов евро. Но вероятнее всего у вас это: https://geektimes.ru/post/270502/

Comment: Мы создавали и поддерживали ряд сайтов с сертификатами от Cloudflare и наши заказчики в России ни разу не видели проблем. Полагаю, что у вас причина в том, что вы не указываете промежуточный сертификат - от Cloudflare до Comodo. Его можно найти на сайте Cloudflare.

Comment: А когда вы установили сертификат ? давно ?  у вас 128- или 256-битное шифрование ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign можете пожалуйста рассказать поподробнее об промежуточном сертификате? Я в cloudflare просто включил flexible сертификат, указал использование https, и вроде бы все нормально, но при проверке сайта через ping-admin в некоторых русских и СНГ городах выдает ошибку "Проблема с соединением через SSL. Скорее всего на сервере отключены ряд шифров для SSL, из-за чего некоторые клиенты не смогут подключиться. "

Comment: @turik97 Надо обязательно включать full (strict) - без этого работать с вашим сертификатом правильно не будет. А про промежуточный сертификат я написал в ответе.

Comment: @Arsen Больше года назад. Cloudflare поддерживает SHA 2 ECDSA.

Answer (score 1):

Выдаваемые Cloudflare сертификаты подписаны самим Cloudflare, как промежуточным центром сертификации. По разным причинам, не все клиентские устройства способны проверить действительность сертификата самого Cloudflare.

Вам нужно добавить в файл сертификата вашего сайта промежуточный сертификат Cloudflare, который можно [скачать здесь](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-). Ваш файл после этого примет такой вид:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE ..... (ваш сертификат)
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID..... (промежуточный сертификат Cloudflare)
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Полученный файл с двумя сертификатами нужно положить в то же самое место на сервер или shared-хостинг, где сейчас находится сертификат вашего сайта.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку насчет " full (strict)", сейчас попробую переключить на него, но вот у меня такой вопрос, вы сказали что нужно добавить к файлу сертификата ещё и промежуточный сертификат. Но что делать если у меня нет этих файлов сертификата? SSL я включил только в ПУ CloudFlare, при этом не устанавливая ничего на свою ВПС, и все практически работает нормально, только вот у некоторых людей не заходит из за ошибки подлинности сертификата

Comment: @turik97 надо генерировать свой сертификат, добавлять к нему промежуточный, заливать это на VPS, включать strict (full). Только так не будет проблем.

Comment: понятно спасибо, а сгенерировать можно непосредственно на самом КлаудФларе? Или это уже отдельный момент

Comment: @turik97 Cloudflare предоставляет бесплатные сертификаты на 15 лет. Сгенерировать такой сертификат можно, нажав на кнопку Crypto. На этой странице возле "Origin Certificates" есть кнопка "Create Certificate". Нажмите ее, получите сертификат и инструкции по установке (в самом низу окна с новым сертификатом)