# ошибка при создании сертификата SSL

Tags: ssl

я использую SSL сертификат от CloudFlare, вот эти записи я добавил в конфиг вирт хоста nginx (в этих файлах хранится сгенерированный ключ от cloudflare)

```
      listen     443;
  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/gs.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/gs.key;
```

но дело в том что после попытки перезагрузить nginx мне выдается такая ошибка:

```
start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib) 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Директивы nginx правильные, ошибка в ключе где-то. Файл ключа должен начинаться с `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE` и заканчиваться `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: @KAGGDesign http://imgur.com/rqaJr1o - вроде правильно все (в обеих файлах одинаковое содержимое).. может всё дело в том что я не устанавливал никакого дополнительного софта для SSL и тд? На VPS только веб сервер, ну и php mysql и тд.

Comment: @turik97 Как это одинаковое??? Файл .pem должен содержать публичный ключ, а .key - ваш приватный! Показывать его никому нельзя, а вы .key выложили на картинке )) Идите и заново генерируйте ключи ))

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо большое, вы уже не раз сделали мой день, простите а вы не можете подсказать, мне осталось сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699180/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-comodo что что вы сказали здесь, но что делать если я не создавал этот файл сертификата?

Comment: @turik97 откуда вы его тогда взяли? Его надо сгенерировать на cloudflare. Не понимаю вопроса, в общем.

Comment: @KAGGDesign просто нужно больше спать, сорри за тупизм и спасибо ещё раз за инфу

Comment: @turik97 Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я бы с радостью, но то твинковый одноразовый акк для задачи вопроса, потому что  на своем у мня все плохо с репутацией))

Comment: @turik97 у меня сложилось стойкое впечатление, что все 3 аккаунта - ваши )). И в любом случае, галочку можно поставить всегда, независимо от репутации. Это не плюсик.